# Convert csv table into hierarchy / stratify doesnt work (want to build a treemap)

Tags: d3.js

i have the following csv table saved to a file data.csv

- Stock_Short, Country, LScore2, MarketCAPUSD
- ZYNE,US,-4,181623392
- ZYME,US,-4,477151488
- ZUO,US,-6,2098448000
- ZUMZ,US,3,685746624
- ...

which goes on for several countries: US, L, HK, DE, etc.

I want to build a treemap in d3 and it uses only a hierarchical list of entries.

I was able to

```
d3.nest
```

the data by country and then tried using

```
d3.stratify
```

but it complains about a missing root. what am i doing wrong? 
i see on this page there is an example of stratify without using a root.
why is mine not working?
https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#stratify

here is the data as a gist:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/a3igner/8935d1e1158898540a615900a8dcb249/raw/5c957cc489ba5049cdc81ef47c3688b7816fbe69/LeverExample

```
var height = 200;
var width = 500;
var margin = {left: 50,right:50,top:40,bottom:0};

//var tree = d3.tree().size([width,height]);
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width','100%').attr('height','100%');
var chartGroup = svg.append('g').attr('transform','translate('+margin.left+','+margin.top+')');

d3.json("keyedJSON-Lever.json").get(function(error,data){
console.log(data);
// console.log(data[0].children);
// console.log(data[0].children[0].children[1].name);
var nestedData = d3.nest().key(function(d){ return d.country; }).entries(data);
console.log(nestedData);

var treeData = d3.stratify()
          .id(function(d) { return d.stock; })
          .parentId(function(d) { return d.country; })
          (data);
console.log(treeData);

});
```

Comment: Your data has multiple roots. `stratify` needs to have one origin i.e. one country. Do you intend to have all countries or split them by country?

Comment: i need to group by country. Seems odd to me you need to have a root for country as well. then within each country there are all the stocks belonging to that country.
This is my block sofar: http://bl.ocks.org/a3igner/0658ea95abf9c7b729e16ca84906d6f1/9a9e06fead29587c58172e240d9720cc93b4b694

Comment: Your block data is very different than the gist data you mentioned in your original question.

Comment: Ignore the finx500 I cloned the example. Levermann-All-Week15.csv is the table